# How does gapi.auth.checkSession work?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-api-js-client

I have a question regarding the way [gapi.auth.checkSession](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript#gapiauthchecksessionstatesessionparams_callback) work.

I'm trying to detect if a user is signed in to Google.
So I'm running this code :

```
gapi.auth.checkSessionState({
  "client_id" : "<?=$client_id?>", // client_id provided by PHP
  "session_state" : null
},function(status){
  alert(status);
});
```

On Google docs, it is said :

> If the argument is true, the supplied session_state is still valid

But quite unexpectedly, my check returns `true` if the user is **not** signed in to Google, and `false` if he is. I cleared my cache & cookies several times, asked a friend to try, he got the same results.
Is this the normal behavior ? Shouldn't it return `true` if the user is logged **in** ?

In addition, I don't understand why the `client_id` parameter is required ? Do the results depend on what client_id is provided ?

Thank you for your help !